# Cannot save into database PHP/PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Hi there I'm trying to making an admin page where a user can write down an article and send it to the database(I'm using CKE4 editor).

But I got this error:

> CONNECTION TO mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistema_autenticazione;charset=utf8 works
> Notice: Undefined property: Articles::$PDO in /opt/lampp/htdocs/arctosbis/articoli.php on line 52
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/arctosbis/articoli.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/arctosbis/superUtenteprofile.php(95): Articles->save() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/arctosbis/articoli.php on line 52

As you can see from the file below the first line is just a echo i did to be sure i could connect to my database with my **db.php**:

```
    <? php
    $dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistema_autenticazione;charset=utf8";
            try{
                $PDO=new PDO($dsn, "root", "");
                $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                echo "CONNECTION TO ".  $dsn . " works";
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Cannot connect to database";
            }
    ?>
```

But if db.php works and "generates" a $PDO then why it doesn' t work in **articoli.php**(line 52 is commented to make it easy to find) ?

```
    <?php
    require './include/db.php';
    
    class Articles{
    
        private $id;
        private $title;
        private $description;
        private $author;
        private $createdOn;
    
    
        function setId($id){
            $this->id=$id;
        }
        function getId(){
            return $this->$id;
        }
    
        function setTitle($title){
            $this->title=$title;
        }
        function getTitle(){
            return $this->$title;
        }
    
        function setDescription($description){
            $this->description = $description;
        }
    
        function getDescription(){
            return $this->$description;
        }
    
        function setAuthor($author){
            $this->author=$author;
        }
        function getAuthor(){
            return $this->$author;
        }
    
        function setCreatedOn($createdOn){
            $this->createdOn=$createdOn;
        }
        function getCreatedOn(){
            return $this->$createdOn;
        }
    
    
        public function save(){
            $sql="INSERT INTO articoli(id,titolo,descrizione,autore,dataCreazione)VALUES (null, :title, :descp, :author, :cdate)";//table name in db and columns i need to insert into
            $stmt =$this->PDO->prepare($sql); //THIS IS LINE 52
    
            $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
            $stmt->bindParam(':descp', $this->description);
            $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cdate', $this->createdOn);
    
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        public function update(){
            //update function
        }
    
        public function getArticleById(){
            //how to retrive articlles from database, by id...
        }
    
    
    
    }
    ?>
```

And finally this is the html/php code form the page where i'm calling the save function

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_REQUEST['save'])){
                        require "articoli.php";
                        $objArticle = new Articles();

                        //set binding parameters
                        $objArticle->setTitle($_REQUEST['save']);
                        $objArticle->setDescription($_REQUEST['editor1']);
                        $objArticle->setAuthor($_REQUEST['author']);
                        $objArticle->setCreatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

                        if($objArticle->save()){
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <div id="result">Subimtted successfully.</div>
                            </div>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <div id="result">Failed to submit</div>
                            </div>';
                        }
                    }

                 ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                <form id="article-frm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="aid" id="aid" value="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon addon-diff-color">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Inserisci un titolo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon addon-diff-color">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Autore">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="editor1">Articolo</textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Create Article" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="save" name="save">

                    </div>

                </form>
```

This is my first project so maybe I'm doing something stupid but sadly I cannot see it.

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATE**

I solved this issue doing:

- Adding to the class **Articles** the function __construct which defines a new PDO object and connection.
- Then  simply add this object(i called it dbh) to the save function

the code:

```
    <?php
    
    class Articles{
    
        private $id;
        private $title;
        private $description;
        private $author;
        private $createdOn;
        private $dbh;
    
        public function __construct() {
            $this->dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistema_autenticazione;", 'root', '');
        }
//.....
```

Alright that was it, not a big deal at all, *mundane* actually but i couldn't see the mistake by myself, therefore thank you all.
Here a link about PDO and how to *deal* with it:

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Object properties do not use `$` after the `->` unless you're using a dynamic name. Change all of the `$this->$` to `$this->`

Comment: Also, at no point do you initialize `$this->PDO`. Requiring `db.php` does not create the class property